# How do Android applications quit?

Tags: android, qt, task, kill

I've read all the questions related to quitting Android application. But I could not find the answer to my problem.

So what is my problem. My application is a music player written in Qt (C++/QML). I wrote it especially for my car. First it was a UMPC with Windows, now I have an aftermarket headunit with Android. I successfully ported my player to Android.

Now I try to solve following issue. If I shut off my car, the Android "computer" inside my radio also shuts down. I would like to save the current track and the track progress so I can resume it on next start.

Is it possible to catch the signal from Android that my app should close and save the settings? Or does Android kill my application without giving me a chance to react to it?

Currently I'm saving the progress to a database every 10 seconds. But I feel this not ideal. I would like to know how applications are closed in Android in these situations:

1) The app is in background and OS decides it needs more RAM and terminates it
2) User invokes app switching menu a swipes my application away
3) System shuts down
4) A "battery saver" (task killer) closes my application

Can I react on some of these situations and do something before my app is closed.

Comment: Did you try `onDestroy()`?

Comment: I write it using C++, so I can not get this signal.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ApplicationWindow` (you mention you are using QML so you should be using that) it is trivial:

```
onClosing: {
    saveYourSettings()
    close.accepted = true
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not that simple. This was my first attempt which wasn't even working on desktop OSs. I need to call the "saveSettings" function on the C++ part. But the applications was sometimes closed before the settings were saved, or it exited with an error. In the end I implemented an eventFilter which catches QEvent::Close and saves the settings before my application quits. Unfortunately this doesn't work on Android.

Comment: You can call C++ functions from QML, just expose them as members of a context property object. Also, it does work as expected on desktop platforms, tested in windows and linux.

Comment: Sorry I posted my comment before it was complete. I know how to call a C++ function from QML and vice-versa but as I wrote this doesn't work. I found a solution which works everywhere except of Android (or maybe other mobile OSs) becasue they have different app life cycle then desktop.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your code, `close.accepted = true` will not be executed before `saveYourSettings()` returns. And the app will not exit before the close event is accepted. I am using this for a quitting confirmation / save unsaved dialogs and such and it has always worked as expected.

Comment: And does it work on Android? For me it works fine on desktop but not on Android.

Comment: onClosing is not the most solid piece of software. See e.g https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-51707 and https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-51590 to name just bugs I am aware of.

Comment: Yes it works as expected, as I already mentioned. Feel free to pursue some hacky or non-portable solution if you so chose, but that's the simplest and most straightforward approach. That's what you should be using. If you want to be extra sure work is done before you quit, have a `property bool canExit : false` and use `close.accepted = canExit` and `onCanExitChanged: if (canExit) close()` and set `canExit` to true only after the settings have been saved.

Comment: @SimonWarta - good to know, I haven't experienced any problems though.